# VB.NET 2013: Change label text

Tags: mysql, vb.net, dynamic, label

I've been teaching myself VB.NET for a couple of weeks now, and I'm stumped. I have 18+ years experience in PHP, and so far the logic has been very similar. What I can't figure out is how to dynamically specify a label to change the text. What I have is 50 labels, one for each state. Then I have a MySQL query pulling a count for that state and then updating the label for the state.

My code currently is:

```
While dataReader.Read
   If dataReader.Item("state") = "CO" Then
     lblCO.Text = "(" & dataReader.Item("total") & ")"
     lblCO.Visible = True
   End If
End While
```

What I don't want to do is make 50 "IF" statements to specify the new text for each label. Each of the labels start with lbl and end with the two state abbreviation. For example: lblCA, lblCO, lblFL.

I thought I could concatenate like this: (similar style of concatenating in PHP)

```
While dataReader.Read
   lbl&dataReader.Item("state").Text = "(" & dataReader.Item("total") & ")"
   lbl&dataReader.Item("state").Visible = True
End While
```

I quickly found out that you can't concatenate like this in VB.NET.

Does anyone know how to do this dynamically? Or am I stuck making 50 "IF" statements?

Thank you!

Comment: try `FORMNAME.Controls("lbl" & dataReader.Item("state").Text)` as the reference. if the labels are on a panel, change form to the panel name.

Comment: Wasn't PHP created in 1995?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first want to thank Plutonix and Mike_OBrien. I was able to combine both of your responses to make a solution that worked perfect for me.

Plutonix: I figured out you had the ".Text" in the wrong place, but overall your snippet worked. Oh, in VB.NET 2013, it forced me to use "Me." instead of the form name.

Mike_OBrien: I liked your "IsNot Nothing" check

The solution that worked perfect for me:

```
 While dataReader.Read
   If Me.Controls("lbl" & dataReader.Item("state")) IsNot Nothing Then
     Me.Controls("lbl" & dataReader.Item("state")).Text = "(" & dataReader.Item("total") & ")"
     Me.Controls("lbl" & dataReader.Item("state")).Visible = True
   End If
 End While
```

So the above will make sure that the label exists. If it does exist, then it will update the text to the count that was pulled from MySQL. Like I said before, I'm very new to VB.NET. So even though the code above works, if anyone knows a reason that what I figured out might be bad for the application or system, I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: its hard to tell from the snippet you posted but in my opinion data readers are less than ideal for most situations. They open a connection to the database and then never let it go for the life of the reader. In my opinion you'd be much better off going to the database at the beginning of your forms life cycle and loading whatever information you need at that time and then using the information in memory to do whatever you need to do. If you ever want to multi-thread the program or have two users access the same table in your database at the same time a `datareader` could cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are in the code behind of the form you are trying to manipulate you could do:

```
Dim currControl = From r In Me.Controls Where DirectCast(r, Control).Name = "lbl" & StateAbbreviation Select r
```

You only need the `DirectCast` portion if you have `option strict` on otherwise you can do:

```
Dim currControl = From r As Control In Me.Controls Where r.Name = "lbl" & StateAbbreviation Select r
```

replace StateAbbreviation with whichever state you are currently trying to edit.

then do:

```
If currControl IsNot Nothing AndAlso currControl.Any Then
    currControl(0).Text = "Whatever you want to assign to the label"
End If
```

This requires .NET 3.5 or greater. But it basically just uses LINQ to find the control you want to edit and then uses the reference to that control to set the display value.